# Finding the output of a node with two diodes (kind of full-wave rectifier)

Tags: diodes, rectifier, kirchhoffs-laws

Maybe this question sound stupid, but I really suck at electronics.

I have this circuit here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZYGa4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and i want to find the values of `U1` when `u0` is:

- u0 = +15 V
- u0 = -10 V
- u0 = +3 V
- u0 = 0 V

Diode tension threshold is 0.6 V.

This is my first post here, so if i messed up with anything please let me know.

EDIT: i fixed D2

Comment: That's not a full-wave rectifier. It won't convert negative AC into positive.

Comment: Did you get the diagram right? As it is, D3 will never conduct.

Comment: D3 will conduct when U0 is negative

Comment: D2 limits the positive voltage at u1 to roughly 0.7V, while D3 limits the positive voltage at u1 to roughly 5.7V. Does this help you already?

Comment: @tik tok algerie: wrong. D3 conducts when u1 is higher than roughly 5.7V.

Comment: D2 is inverted (period) and this is almost an input ESD protection circuit for analog or digital, if it were 10k instead of 100. But could be an output ESD protection for drivers.  D2 will burn out before d3 conducts.

Comment: @ oh s***t i messed up, it is actually 10k i will edit it .

Comment: What will the current through D2 be when u1 is at 5.7V?

Comment: i fixed D2, is it full wave now??????

Comment: No, why do you think it is a full wave rectifier? It does not rectify anything, it clips.

Comment: @ justme, i am just stuck at the node, so i want to calculate U1

Comment: your have used the term `U1` twice now, yet your diagram shows `u1` .... the two are not the same

Answer (score 1):

Steps to get your answers:

Look at the diagram. In the simple diode model (fixed 0.6V drop) the diodes act like pressure (voltage) operated valves: any voltage over 0.6V (difference between the two diode pins in forward direction) will be shorted (bleeded). When there is less voltage over a diode, it will not conduct, it might as well not be there at all.

So, first look at D3. At which voltage will it start conduction? Which voltages at u1 are impossible because D3 would (over-) conduct?

Now apply the same logic to D2. It will start conduction when u1 is *below* a certain voltage.

Now you have the range of possible voltages at u1. Check your list of input voltages against this range.